# Pre-built images deployed directly onto machines without Virtualization

Tags: linux, deployment, imaging

I'm looking into a solution for our QA department that allows them to create a set of operating system images and deploy them to multiple machines from a central server without using virtualization.

Does anyone have any recommendations on a solution for this? (paid or otherwise)

Comment: is there a reason you are ruling out virtualization?

Comment: We already have a virtualized environment. We need to test both.

Comment: FYI we are planning on using Linux and Windows images

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Along with the others mentioned there is [FOG](http://www.fogproject.org/).  A network based solution that uses images stored on a central server and pxe boot for deployment.

Comment: it's the only one mentioned so far that i know can dump a whole OS image from a server.  centrally managed too.

Answer (score 2):

Ghost, Acronis, WDS (formerly RIS), Altiris

Comment: Except that RIS is now WDS

Comment: @mfinni - I guess you can pick which option I listed that I haven't used in a while :)

Answer (score 2):

Windows? WDS - works perfectly. The good thing is that it is not a disc image, it images on the file system level (like a zip file, with all attributes), so the disc size is not important.

"ImageX" is the command you look for to make an image copy from an existing disc.